# Javascript time out div

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

I have an alert that says you're right/wrong. I want to put a div that will appear for a few seconds instead of the alert. So when the right/wrong answer is chosen this div will appear instead of the alert. I know a timeout function would be needed but I cant seem to get it to work. I've tried a few times and nothing is working for me. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

This is the html (divs)

```
<div id = "your wrong"> 
wrong answer!
</div>


<div id = "right answer">
Right answer! 
</div>
```

This is the javascript for the alert

```
function characterclicked(nr) {  

if (nr == oddoneout[currentQuestionIndex].answer) {  
alert("You're right!");
score+= 200;;
}
else{
alert("you are wrong it was " +   oddoneout[currentQuestionIndex].characterName);
}

nextQuestion();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about the only thing you're not allowed to use in an `id` value in HTML is a space. :-) So we'll need to change those `id`s.

But then it's a simple matter of having them start off invisible (`display: none`), showing the relevant one (`display: block`), and then hiding it again after a delay via `setTimeout`.

```js
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = function() {
  show("right");
};
document.getElementById("btnWrong").onclick = function() {
  show("wrong");
};

function show(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
}
```

```html
<div id="wrong" style="display: none">
wrong answer!
</div>

<div id="right" style="display: none">
Right answer! 
</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="Show Right">
  <input type="button" id="btnWrong" value="Show Wrong">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will hope help you

```js
var score = 0;
var oddoneout = Array();
oddoneout[0] = {answer: "2"};
var currentQuestionIndex = 0;

var btnReply = document.getElementById("reply");

btnReply.onclick = function(){
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    characterclicked(answer);
};

function characterclicked(nr) {  
    var feedback = document.getElementById("right_answer");
    if (nr == oddoneout[currentQuestionIndex].answer) { 
        score+= 200;
    }else{
        //alert("you are wrong it was " +   oddoneout[currentQuestionIndex].characterName);
        feedback = document.getElementById("your_wrong");
    }
    feedback.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        feedback.style.display = "none";
    }, 2000);
    //nextQuestion();
}
```

```css
.feedback {
    display: none;
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
    how many is 1 + 1 ?
</div>
<input type="text" id="answer" />
<input type="button" id="reply" value="reply" />
<div id = "your_wrong" class="feedback"> 
wrong answer!
</div>
<div id = "right_answer" class="feedback">
Right answer! 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is to make the element that will contain the message invisible. You can do this by using `display: none`, either in the element's `style` attribute or in a CSS style sheet (preferred).

Next, we'll craft a function that shows the message. Since it can show either one of two messages, it will take an argument, so it knows whether to show "right" or "wrong".

```
function showMessage(right) { ... }
```

The `right` argument can be a boolean to keep it simple. From here, we can use only a single `<div>` and change it's text according to whether or not `right` is true.

Let's give it an `id` of `message` (you were using spaces in your IDs, which you cannot do).

```
function showMessage(right) {
    var text = "You are ";
    text += right? "right" : "wrong";
    // Let's get the result <div>
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");
    // and change it's text
    messageDiv.innerText = text;
}
```

Now, all that's left is to show the message `<div>`, and after a few seconds make it disappear again. Let's use 5 seconds for this example. 5 seconds are 5000 milliseconds, which is what the timeout functions use as a unit.

```
function showMessage(right) {
    var text = "You are ";
    text += right? "right" : "wrong";
    // Let's get the result <div>
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById("message");
    // and change it's text
    messageDiv.innerText = text;
    // and show it, and hide it after 5 seconds
    messageDiv.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function(){
        messageDiv.style.display = "none";    
    }, 5000);
}
```

And that's it! If you call the function with `true` as an argument, it will show you *"You are right"*. Otherwise, it will show you *"You are wrong"*.

Here's a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgrLfzfr/2/) for you to see it working.

*Edit*

If you also want to show the correct answer when the user is wrong, you can do so with a second argument:

```
function showMessage(right, answer) {
    var text = "You are ";
    text += right? "right!" : "wrong. The answer was " + answer;
    ...
}
```